# freemarker template syntax spring boot

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have a springboot application that creates a hashmap. I want to create a table that has one header and multiple rows (one for each value in the map). The following code returns an ISE:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Failed to parse FreeMarker template for URL
>   [toDoListView.ftl]; nested exception is
>   freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template
>   "toDoListView.ftl" in line 47, column 37: Encountered ">", but was
>   expecting one of: ".."  "..*" "as" "." "[" "(" "?" "!"
>    "??" "+" "-" "*" "/" "%" "!=" "=" "==" ">="
>    ">"

line 47 is:<#list itemMap>

```
<#if itemMap??>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <#list itemMap>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Item1</th>
                    <th>Item2</th>
                    <th>Item3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <#item?keys as key>
            <#if !itemMap?values[key_index].done>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="checkbox_column" width="40">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="im" value="${key}">
                        </td>
                        <#if itemMap?values[key_index].color == "BLUE">
                            <td>${itemMap?values[key_index].blue}</td>
                        <#elseif itemMap?values[key_index].color == "RED">
                            <td>${itemMap?values[key_index].red}</td> 
                        </#if>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </#if> 
        </#item?keys>
    </table>
<#else>
    No Items!
</#list>
```

I am not sure what is causing this error. I was trying to follow the example listed here under Form 2: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html

Comment: And `line 47, column 37` is...?

Comment: line 47 is:<#list itemMap>

Comment: As this information is fairly relevant to the question I would suggest you edit it into the answer - perhaps annotate that particular like of code.

Comment: it is in the question, maybe not very visible but it is above the code block :/

Comment: as stated in my question I was following form 2:<#list sequence>
    Part executed once if we have more than 0 items
    <#items as item>
        Part repeated for each item
    </#items>
    Part executed once if we have more than 0 items
<#else>
    Part executed when there are 0 items
</#list>

Comment: Okay, sorry - are you running the newest version?

Comment: im not seeing a version in my dependencies, it says   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: thats probably the problem right there :/

Comment: If you're inheriting from Spring Boot Parent or using the BOM then the version is set automagically - that would then depend on your Boot version.

Comment: Please check `#list` syntax in the official documentation. Sorry, I don't see why anyone else would look for why `#item?keys` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly it's because you are using a FreeMarker version before 2.3.23. Before 2.3.23, you couldn't omit the `as` from the `#list` tag. (You also have some messy parts later like `<#itemMap?keys as key>` or `</#listy?keys>`, but I assume you can fix those.)

To check the FreeMarker version, try `${.version}` (after removing the syntactically wrong parts). To increase the FreeMarker version coming from the Spring BOM, override it in your POM's `dependencyManagement` section. Something like:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  ...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.23</version>
  <dependency>
  ...
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest version and updated the errors in the template that you noted, but it doesnt appear to like <#items?keys as key> because it returns: Syntax error in template #items is an existing directive, but the tag is malformed.

Comment: Or you can just put `<freemarker.version>2.3.32</freemarker.version>` or whichever version in the `<properties>` section of your `pom.xml`.